# The Layout/Style of radio button is different when I add it to listview with customadaptor

Tags: android, layout, android-listview, radio-button

I am using radio buttons and check boxes in list view. When I fill the list view with Custom Adapter, Radio button style is changed along with check boxes style. When I add it to list view without Custom Adapter in XML then its style is default. XML layout of list view item is attached.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- TextView for displaying question-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/check"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- RadioGroup for grouping of RadioButton-->

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbutt1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="15"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbutt2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="30"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbutt3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="45"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Adding Radio Buttons to List view

```
    //=========================================================================================================
// get the string array from string.xml file
        questions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);
// get the reference of ListView and Button
        simpleList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.simpleListView);
        submit = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.submit);
// set the adapter to fill the data in the ListView
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getContext().getApplicationContext(), questions);
        simpleList.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        //=========================================================================================================
```

[Added with custom Adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWMBa.png)

[Added in XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXdvq.png)